# Break an array of objects into separate arrays based on value of property

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like so:

`dates = [{date: 20180227},{date: 2018028},{date: 20180305},{date:20180321},{date:20180501},{date:20180604}]`

what I want to know is how I can group these objects into separate arrays where they are sorted by their month, like:

`feb = [{date: 20180227},{date: 2018028}],
 mar = [{date: 20180305},{date:20180321}],
 may = [{date:20180501}],
 jun = [{date:20180604}]`

I just need them in separate arrays based on the dates. How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Could you please show the code you have tried

Comment: Let me bring you a coffee, sec. Btw, that's just some logic YOU have to implement. not so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a map of `months` first.

```
var months = { "01" : "jan", "02" : "feb", "03" : "mar", "04" : "apr", "05" : "may", "06" : "jun", "07" : "jul", "08" : "aug", "09" : "sep", "10" : "oct", "11" : "nov", "12" : "dec" };
```

Use `reduce`

```
var output = dates.reduce( (a,c) => {
   var month = String(c.date).substring(4,6); //extract month
   a[ months[ month ] ] = a[ months[ month ] ] || []; //initialize array for that month bucket
   a[ months[ month ] ].push( c ); //push the object to that month bucket
   return a; //return accumulator
} ,{})
```